# Making a matrix positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Suppose $p \times p$ matrix $X$ is symmetric and not positive definite (PD). I want to find the minimum value for $\mu$ such that $X + \mu I_p$ is positive definite. To this end, I suppose we can solve a semidefinite program (SDP) of the form

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mu\\ \text{subject to} & X + \mu I_p  \succeq 0\\ & \mu \geq 0\end{array}$$

where $A \succeq 0$ denotes that matrix $A$ is PD, and $I_p$ is the $p \times p$ identity matrix.

Is there a more elegant approach to find $\mu$ using linear algebra? I am also curious if $\mu$ has any interpretation or not.

Thanks for possible feedback!

Comment: Just let $\mu$ to be the absolute value of the smallest eigenvalue of $X$ (since $X$ is not PD, this must be $\geq 0$).

Comment: @Wanshan, thanks. this makes sense.

Comment: Are you assuming $X$ is symmetric?

Comment: @kimchilover Yes. Thanks for this important note. Edited the question. Does this change anything?

Comment: If the matrix is symmetrical then you have [real eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) which makes it possible to apply Wanshan's idea.